# Convert List of object into another List of object

Tags: c#, linq, type-conversion

I have a list as

```
class Vachel
{
int id{get;set;}
int vachelid {get;set;}
string title {get;set;}
}
```

List of Vachel
as

```
id  vachelid  title
1   2         bus
1   3         truck
2   4         cycle
2   5         bike
2   5         bick
```

And I want to convert `List<Vachel>` to `List<Result>`

```
class Result
{
int id{get;set;}
string vachelid {get;set;}
string title {get;set;}
}
```

And the result must be as

```
   id   vachelid    title
    1   2,3         bus,truck
    2   4,5         cycle,bike,bick
```

I tried as

```
List<Vachel> V = getList();
List<Result> R = null;
 R = V.GroupBy(x=> new{x.vachelid})
    .Select
       (
       x=> new Result
         {
         id  =x.Key.id,
         vachelid =x.FirstOrDefault().vachelid,
         title   =x.FirstOrDefault().title
         }
       ).ToList();
```

Here I know I want to put something instead of `.FirstOrDefault().vachelid` and `.FirstOrDefault().title` but I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
R = V.GroupBy(x => x.id)
     .Select(g => new Result(){
        id = g.Key,
        vachelid = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.vachelid).Distinct()),
        title = string.Join(",", g.Select(x => x.title).Distinct()),
     }).ToList();
```

Comment: @user2641905: sorry, I am not following you, could you elaborate more?

Comment: plz have a look question again.

Comment: @user2641905: I have looked again but still did not get your point, please could you use English in decent *if i want uniqes vales only seperet by*?

Comment: here in List Vechle, for vecheleid = 5 there is two Title bike and bick and i want result as vecheleid = 5 and title = bike,bick from your code i get vechelid = 4,5,5 and Title = cycle,bike,bick
but i only want vechelid = 4,5 and Title = cycle,bike,bick

Comment: @user2641905: got it, I have changed my answer

Comment: oww that's great can you refer me 1 exciting link for learning LINQ in depth